# Windows 10 Wifi keeps disconnecting from access point

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I recently purchased a refurbished HP Laptop 17-bs1xx. It has an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 network adapter, running Windows 10 Home, 64-bit.

Periodically, sometimes every few minutes to every few days, whatever I'm streaming or downloading just stops, and after about 10-20 seconds, the Wifi icon flickers from connected to the not-connected-but-connections-available, and then a few seconds later goes back to being connected.

After complaining to my ISP, they told me it was a device issue, as my modem showed no downtime. So, my next attempt was to update the drivers and see if that helps. Using the built-in HP Support tool, I updated all drivers to the latest version. Using Intel's Device Driver tool, I also updated the drivers there, too (both Wifi and Bluetooth were updated). I also made sure to check Windows Update to make sure I'm on the latest version.

After all the updates and reboots, it happened again, and so I checked the Windows Event Viewer. In there, corresponding to each time the Wifi disconnected, I see either one of two messages:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Netwtw04
Date:          8/12/2018 3:58:21 PM
Event ID:      5035
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      LAPTOP-553FAOH6
Description:
5035 - Driver OSC Pending OID watchdog
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Netwtw04" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">5035</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-08-12T21:58:21.374492400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>11334</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>LAPTOP-553FAOH6</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\NDMP2</Data>
    <Data>Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168</Data>
    <Binary>000004000200340000000000AB1300C000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000057445256</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

---

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Netwtw04
Date:          8/12/2018 3:48:51 PM
Event ID:      5007
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      LAPTOP-553FAOH6
Description:
5007 - TX/CMD timeout (TfdQueue hanged)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Netwtw04" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">5007</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-08-12T21:48:51.688121200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>11327</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>LAPTOP-553FAOH6</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\NDMP2</Data>
    <Data>Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168</Data>
    <Binary>0000080002003800000000008F1300C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004D4D41431C001509</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

---

Searching through HP and Intel support forums, I've seen people asking this question, but no other solutions than "try updating your drivers." There also doesn't seem to be any relevant answers here on SU, either.

Is there anything else I can do besides invoking my extended warranty plan, which will take 1-2 weeks? It's not annoying enough to warrant losing my box for a few weeks, but it is annoying enough that I'd really like to try and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following steps.

1. Open `Control panel`, and click `view by` to select `small icons`
2. Click Power Options
3. Find the current plans (in my PC is `Balanced`)
4. Click `Change plan settings`
5. Click `Change advanced power settings` in the new Window
6. In the new Window, click `Change settings that are current unavailable`
7. Then find `Wireless Adapter Settings` -> `Power Saving Mode` -> `Settings`
8. Change it as `Maximum Performance`

Or try disable power management in the adapter settings.

1. Open the `properties` of your wireless network adapter which is used
2. Click `Configure` under the properties
3. Click the `Advanced` tab, and then modify the `power management` settings. Or disable it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my power plan is always configured for Maximum Performance.

Comment: The dust must have settled on this fight now, but have you checked the Power management tab under your adapter properties? There's this pesky option to "Allow Windows to turn this device off to save power" that's enabled by default on every power plan...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this instantly by running the network reset option in windows 10. This reinstalls all the drivers. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).